# styling bullet points in css

Tags: html, css

Ok this might be a stupid question but i am going mad about this bullet point styling. 
I am trying to make it look like this :

```
 - Coffee                        - Milk                   - Milk
 - Coffee                        - Milk                   - Milk
 - Coffee                        - Milk                   - Milk
```

Using this markup

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? You want your bullets to display as A, B, C or what..?

Comment: Agree with Gavin, even with your example.. I'm not sure what you're trying to do

Comment: Sorry that was a crap example, i want them to be displayed like this, so the letters etc will be replaced by text but its the atually way they are laied out, if that makes sense?

Comment: Posted above, the layout is what i am looking for

Comment: You're still giving no good explanation on what you're looking for...

Comment: Add your code and maybe we can help

Comment: Did you try `li { float:left; }` ?

Comment: I really done know how to make this any more clear, i just want 3 Colosseum of bullet point, So they way they are above, that is what i am looking to do , will post again to exaplion

Comment: Dunno why so many down votes will re ask this question if this is much problem it has cuased its stilly

Comment: It was hard to understand what you were asking, as I read it as to mean the styling of the bullet points themselves, not the layout of the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, using `inline-block`

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Can be done with `flex`

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}
li {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you x for the help

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 30%;
}
li:before {
content: "-";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  float:left;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
   <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  margin: 0;
}    
ul {
  list-style-image: url(images/bullet.png);
}
```

its the easy way to do it.